# Scaffold-DbContext doese not add [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Computed)] on Generated class

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

I am using EF Core 3.1 with a database-first approach using Linq-to-Entities.
but when I cerate my models with this code

```
Scaffold-DbContext "Server=xxxx;Database=xx;Trusted_Connection=True;Integrated security=false;User id=xx;Password=xx;" Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer -f -OutputDir Models
```

it does not add proper `[DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Computed)]` on generated class properties with default values.

this is my table Script :

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[member](
    [id] [bigint] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [fName] [nvarchar](20) NOT NULL,
    [lName] [nvarchar](30) NOT NULL,
    [gender] [bit] NOT NULL,
    [birthDate] [date] NULL,
    [education] [tinyint] NOT NULL,
    [province] [tinyint] NOT NULL,
    [image] [nvarchar](200) NOT NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_Member] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [id] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]

GO

SET ANSI_PADDING OFF
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[member] ADD  CONSTRAINT [DF_member_gender]  DEFAULT ((0)) FOR [gender]
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[member] ADD  CONSTRAINT [DF_member_birthDate]  DEFAULT (NULL) FOR [birthDate]
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[member] ADD  CONSTRAINT [DF_member_education]  DEFAULT ((1)) FOR [education]
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[member] ADD  CONSTRAINT [DF_member_province]  DEFAULT ((1)) FOR [province]
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[member] ADD  CONSTRAINT [DF_member_image]  DEFAULT ('') FOR [image]
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[member]  WITH CHECK ADD  CONSTRAINT [FK_Member_education] FOREIGN KEY([education])
REFERENCES [dbo].[education] ([id])
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[member] CHECK CONSTRAINT [FK_tblMember_education]
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[member]  WITH CHECK ADD  CONSTRAINT [FK_Member_Province] FOREIGN KEY([province])
REFERENCES [dbo].[province] ([id])
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[member] CHECK CONSTRAINT [FK_Member_Province]
GO
```

Comment: Please provide a sample `CREATE TABLE` statement for one of the tables (generated by Management Studio or so) that are getting scaffolded incorrectly.

Comment: @lauxjpn I edited my question

Answer (score 0):

When scaffolding the database (without the `--data-annotations` option), the following Fluent API calls get generated, including the corresponding `.HasDefaultValueSql()` calls:

```cs
protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    modelBuilder.Entity<Member>(entity =>
    {
        entity.ToTable("member");

        entity.Property(e => e.Id).HasColumnName("id");

        entity.Property(e => e.BirthDate)
            .HasColumnName("birthDate")
            .HasColumnType("date");

        entity.Property(e => e.Education)
            .HasColumnName("education")
            .HasDefaultValueSql("((1))");

        entity.Property(e => e.FName)
            .IsRequired()
            .HasColumnName("fName")
            .HasMaxLength(20);

        entity.Property(e => e.Gender).HasColumnName("gender");

        entity.Property(e => e.Image)
            .IsRequired()
            .HasColumnName("image")
            .HasMaxLength(200)
            .HasDefaultValueSql("('')");

        entity.Property(e => e.LName)
            .IsRequired()
            .HasColumnName("lName")
            .HasMaxLength(30);

        entity.Property(e => e.Province)
            .HasColumnName("province")
            .HasDefaultValueSql("((1))");
    });

    OnModelCreatingPartial(modelBuilder);
}
```

When scaffolding the database with the `--data-annotations` option, most meta data will be added using data annotations, but even here the following Fluent API calls get generated:

```cs
protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    modelBuilder.Entity<Member>(entity =>
    {
        entity.Property(e => e.Education).HasDefaultValueSql("((1))");

        entity.Property(e => e.Image).HasDefaultValueSql("('')");

        entity.Property(e => e.Province).HasDefaultValueSql("((1))");
    });

    OnModelCreatingPartial(modelBuilder);
}
```

So the generated scripts are correct.

It is theoreticall possible to use the `[DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]` data annotation to signal that the database will generate values by itself when adding an entity.

However, this would not preserve the information of *what* value this would be, because the `[DatabaseGenerated]` attribute does not have a property to specify a default value. Since you might want to use migrations after you scaffolded the database, the default value meta data might be quite useful.

By the way, there are no default value calls generated for the `BirthDate` and `Gender` properties, because their database defined `DEFAULT` constraint are the same as the CLR default value of those types (`null` for `DateTime?` and `false` for `bool`).

---

As a sidenote, I consider using `[DatabaseGenerated]` as confusing/misleading, because of its outdated option names. The Fluent API with its `HasDefaultValue()`, `HasDefaultValueSql()`, `HasComputedColumnSql()`, `ValueGeneratedOnAdd()` and `ValueGeneratedOnAddOrUpdate()` methods is quite expressive in comparison and should be used instead even in cases where not explicitly necessary.